# ORA-00904: invalid identifier, when column title is correct

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, ora-00904

I have a large SQL query (15m runtime) **created by someone else** that I recently added a new column "SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL".  Now I'm getting an ORA-00904 error... But the name is correct and so is the table reference.

In the "Long list of columns" nothing has been changed. There *no* are aliases with "quote marks", and all fields and commands are typed in CAPS LOCK characters. Just to double check, I removed the two new lines, and it ran just fine.

The table DDEF_STAG.SSBSECT has 2 Keys, SSBSECT_TERM_CODE & SSBSECT_CRN. I've quintuple checked the spelling of the field. "SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL" a P5 field.

Doing some more digging, I realized the table is first truncated, the inserted into. Other steps in the query use DROP and CREATE.

Any clues or suggestions?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE DDEF_STAG.SCR_DRIVER;
(Drop all indexes)    
INSERT INTO DDEF_STAG.SCR_DRIVER
    (
       (Long list of columns)
     **SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL**
    )
    SELECT 
     (Long list of columns)
      **DDEF_STAG.SSBSECT.SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL**
    FROM
      DDEF_STAG.STVRSTS,
      DDEF_STAG.STVTERM STVTERM2,
      DDEF_STAG.STVTERM,
      DDEF_STAG.SYRPRLE,
      DDEF_STAG.SCBCRSE_XREF,
      DDEF_STAG.SSBSECT,
      DDEF_STAG.SGBSTDN,
      DDEF_STAG.SGBSTDN_XREF,
      DDEF_STAG.SFRSTCR,
      DDEF_STAG.STUDENT_TOINCLUDE_DWH
    WHERE (giant list of criteria too long to list)
(Recreate all indexes)
```

Comment: where you have (long list of columns) -- you messed something up there, probably

Comment: Run this and let us know if you can see the new column: describe DDEF_STAG.SSBSECT;

Comment: Just to double check, I removed the two new lines, the script  ran just fine. 
The table DDEF_STAG.SSBSECT has 2 Keys, SSBSECT_TERM_CODE & SSBSECT_CRN, both of which are used in the select statement. I've quintuple checked the spelling of the field. "SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL" a P5 field.

Comment: Maybe you just missed a comma before the added column?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem: The table needs to dropped and recreated rather than using the TRUNCATE command.